# Javascript Dropdowns with search feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following codepen page, I have created a JS page. It is basically 2 drop down menus with 2 search boxes however, the search box for the 2nd drop down menu doesn't work.

https://codepen.io/gaurav-gurnani/pen/jOJZvOE

```
function create_custom_dropdowns() {
    $('select').each(function (i, select) {
        if (!$(this).next().hasClass('dropdown-select')) {
            $(this).after('<div class="dropdown-select wide ' + ($(this).attr('class') || '') + '" tabindex="0"><span class="current"></span><div class="list"><ul></ul></div></div>');
            var dropdown = $(this).next();
            var options = $(select).find('option');
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
            dropdown.find('.current').html(selected.data('display-text') || selected.text());
            options.each(function (j, o) {
                var display = $(o).data('display-text') || '';
                dropdown.find('ul').append('<li class="option ' + ($(o).is(':selected') ? 'selected' : '') + '" data-value="' + $(o).val() + '" data-display-text="' + display + '">' + $(o).text() + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });

    $('.dropdown-select ul').before('<div class="dd-search"><input id="txtSearchValue" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="filter()" class="dd-searchbox" type="text"></div>');
}

// Event listeners

// Open/close
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-select', function (event) {
    if($(event.target).hasClass('dd-searchbox')){
        return;
    }
    $('.dropdown-select').not($(this)).removeClass('open');
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).find('.option').attr('tabindex', 0);
        $(this).find('.selected').focus();
    } else {
        $(this).find('.option').removeAttr('tabindex');
        $(this).focus();
    }
});

// Close when clicking outside
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.dropdown-select').length === 0) {
        $('.dropdown-select').removeClass('open');
        $('.dropdown-select .option').removeAttr('tabindex');
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});

function filter(){
    var valThis = $('#txtSearchValue').val();
    $('.dropdown-select ul > li').each(function(){
     var text = $(this).text();
        (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase()) > -1) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();         
   });
};
// Search

// Option click
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-select .option', function (event) {
    $(this).closest('.list').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var text = $(this).data('display-text') || $(this).text();
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-select').find('.current').text(text);
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-select').prev('select').val($(this).data('value')).trigger('change');
});

// Keyboard events
$(document).on('keydown', '.dropdown-select', function (event) {
    var focused_option = $($(this).find('.list .option:focus')[0] || $(this).find('.list .option.selected')[0]);
    // Space or Enter
    //if (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            focused_option.trigger('click');
        } else {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
        return false;
        // Down
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        } else {
            focused_option.next().focus();
        }
        return false;
        // Up
    } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        } else {
            var focused_option = $($(this).find('.list .option:focus')[0] || $(this).find('.list .option.selected')[0]);
            focused_option.prev().focus();
        }
        return false;
        // Esc
    } else if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    create_custom_dropdowns();
});



$(function() {
  // bind change event to select
  $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function() {
  

    var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
    
    

    return false;
  });
   $('#dynamic_select2').on('change', function() {
  
    var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
    

    return false;
  });

 });
```

Comment: you have 2 `<input id="txtSearchValue"` so that's an issue

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning same id (txtSearchValue) on different inputs (as @[Jaromanda X] already noticed).
It's possible to make it work with minimum changes in jquery file.

1. don't duplicate id; it's even not needed actually

```
      //$('.dropdown-select ul').before('<div class="dd-search"><input id="txtSearchValue" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="filter()" class="dd-searchbox" type="text"></div>');
      // replace with
      $.each($('.dropdown-select ul'), function(){
        let $ul = $(this);
        let $ipt = $('<input>',{'type':'text', 'autocomplete':'off'}).addClass('dd-searchbox').on('keyup',function(){
          filter($ul, $ipt);
        });
        $ul.before($('<div>').addClass('dd-search').append($ipt));
      });
```

2. modify the filter() function

```
    function filter($ul, $ipt){
      let valThis = $ipt.val();
      $ul.find('> li').each(function(){
       let text = $(this).text();
          (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase()) > -1) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
     });
    };
```